# htlatex table compilation error using revtex4-1.cls

Tags: latex, tex4ht

I am getting error while converting a LaTeX table to HTML using htlatex. Following is the TeX code:

```
\documentclass[aps,english,prb,reprint,superscriptaddress,citeautoscript,showpacs]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{\label{table1} Table Caption}
\begin{tabular}{lcc} 
abc & def & ghi\\
xyz & pqr & tbl
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The tex code as such works fine. What error do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your support, samcarter!

The error is 

!Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\ar:cnt
1.8 \begin{tabular}{lcc}

I am using MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit Windows OS and I am compiling the file as follows:

htlatex <filename.tex>

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the conflict between htlatex and the revtex4-1 class by using a suitable .4ht configuration file.

I don't know if there is already one for revtex4-1, but for revtex4 there is one available from

http://texlive.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/revtex4.4ht

Download the file, rename it to `revtex4-1.4ht` and place it in the same directory as your .tex file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks hugely, samcarter! It works now. I searched for the revtex4-1.4ht to try few modifications but not found. Meantime, had no idea of renaming the existing revtex4.4ht file. This really worked. Great and Thanks much again.

Comment: @Khizar You're welcome!